# Iterating through Python dictionary very slow

Tags: python

I'm trying to compute the distance between pairs of users based on values of items that are assigned to them. However the distance calculation should be null when the two users do not have any intersecting items. I'm also calculating the lower half of the distance matrix only (eg. UserA-UserB is equivalent to UserB-UserA so only calculate one).

So I have this following Python script that works, but it really starts chugging when I feed it more than a few hundred users. The sample script below shows the input structure, but I'm trying to do thousands, not just the four I have shown here.

The line `s = {k:v for k,v in data.items() if k in (user1,user2)}` seems to add the most overhead

```
import math
from decimal import *

def has_matching_product(data,user1,user2):
    c1=set(data[user1].keys())
    c2=[k for k in data[user2].keys()]
    return any([x in c1 for x in c2])

def get_euclidean_dist(data,user1,user2):
    #Tried subsetting to run quicker?
    s = {k:v for k,v in data.items() if k in (user1,user2)}

    #Ignore users with no overlapping items
    if has_matching_product(s,user1,user2):
        items=set()
        for k,v in s.items():
            for ki in v.keys():
                items.add(ki)

        rs=Decimal(0)
        for i in items:
            p1 = s.get(user1).get(i)
            p2 = s.get(user2).get(i)
            v1 = p1 or 0
            v2 = p2 or 0

            rs+= Decimal((v1-v2)**2)
        return math.sqrt(rs)
    else:
        return None

#User/Product/Value
raw_data = {
    'U1': {
        'I1':5,
        'I4':2
    },
    'U2': {
        'I1':1,
        'I3':6
    },
    'U3': {
        'I3':11
    },
    'U4': {
        'I4':9
    }
}

users = sorted(raw_data.keys())
l = len(users)

data_out = set()
#Compute lower half of a distance matrix (unique pairs only)
for u1 in range(0,l-1):
    for u2 in range(1+u1,l):
        dist = get_euclidean_dist(raw_data,users[u1],users[u2])
        print('{x} | {y} | {d}'.format(x=users[u1],y=users[u2],d=dist)) #Sample output
```

What the proper output should look like:

```
U1 | U2 | 7.483314773547883
U1 | U3 | None
U1 | U4 | 8.602325267042627
U2 | U3 | 5.0990195135927845
U2 | U4 | None
U3 | U4 | None
```

Comment: Why do you need a `sqrt`?

Comment: The distance function is as such https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance

Comment: `s = {k: data[k] for k in (user1, user2) if k in data}`

Comment: Thanks @PeterWood! It dropped the time per loop by 99.6%. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it? Also, what is different between mine and yours?

Comment: Your loop complexity was very high - you would grab `user1`, then grab `user2` so already  `O(n**2)` and then you would sift through all of `data` to find `user1` and `user2` again, raising it to `O(n**3)`; he inverted that last search so it keeps you at `O(n**2)`. The difference when you have, say, 1000 items is the different between a million and a billion (`1000**2` vs `1000**3`) and it only gets worse the more items you have.

Comment: Peter +1, I love that dict comprehension!

Comment: @nigel222 - what do you love about it? Isn't is just basically `if user1 in data and user2 in data:`?

Comment: One of those aha moments. I use comprehensions a lot, but this one wouldn't have sprung into my mind. Now I've seen it ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're walking the ENTIRE dictionary every time, just to find the two items you want. And from the looks of it, you're pulling out the `user`s, and then spending all that time trying to go find them again in `data`. @Peter Wood's suggestion will help a bunch - only grab the two `user`s you want in the first place, but that's sort of missing the forest from the trees - you don't need to slim down your dictionary in the first place at all. Keep it all together:

```
import itertools
for kv1, kv2 in itertools.combinations(data.items(), 2):
    ## calculate distance directly here
```

Comment: Yes, the dict comprehension I suggested was an improvement but still needed to search the keys for each user. Your solution side-steps the issue completely.

Answer (score 2):

You are using decimal, which is not very fast. Dictionaries are already a set of keys, so creating extra sets is not neccessary.
You create a list with `any` which must calculate all values, use a generator instead.
You are using `get` so you can provide a default value.
So i get this:

```
import math

def get_euclidean_dist(data,user1,user2):
    c1 = data[user1]
    c2 = data[user2]
    #Ignore users with no overlapping items
    if any(x in c1 for x in c2):
        items = set(c1)
        items.update(c2)
        rs = sum((c1.get(i, 0)-c2.get(i, 0))**2 for i in items)
        return math.sqrt(rs)
    else:
        return None
```